# How to request an FAQ for a topic

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Is there a specific (and polite) way to request an FAQ for a topic?  That is, if I am working in a field that has limited online documentation, is there a proper way to request a Stack Overflow user begin an FAQ detailing some basics on that topic?

Perhaps the poster should place a significant bounty with that request (500?) as an FAQ on a less-known topic/language/technology could be a lot of work.  That said, I'm unaware of a format for asking not just a question, but for a topic to be elaborated on in FAQ format.

(Perhaps all FAQs are currently created organically -- in the which case this becomes a feature request: have an FAQ w\bounty section where users can post desired topics and associated bounties for FAQs written on them.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A request to create a FAQ is not on topic for Stack Overflow. While un- and underdocumented software products are troubling, Stack Overflow is not the place to fill that general void in the market *in a single question.*

If the product in question is reasonably popular, and the questions surrounding it are programming related, a general FAQ will emerge organically via our normal question and answer system. When questions are appropriately tagged, users will be able to search on the tag and see all questions for it, and this information will be indexed in the major search engines. Additionally, you will be able to create tag wikis that have more information about the product, and can add whatever information that is relevant to assist users with finding help.

Comment: Ah, okay.  I wasn't sure on the scope of SO despite having read the About page(s).  I have enjoyed the quality of the existing FAQs and wondered if this was acceptable.  Apparently it is not.  Thanks!